# Best compression of similar files?

Tags: compression

I've got a few full old backups of things like binary database dumps. Obviously, they don't differ much so doing full backups is not the smartest idea here. For now, I'm looking for a compression program capable of taking an advantage from the fact, that most of the files have a similar content.

Comment: Tried lrzip? http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/lrzip/README

Comment: [Obnam](http://liw.fi/obnam/) is a backup tool featuring de-duplication ([see this LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/500346/)).

Comment: Not sure I entirely understood the question but does [`rdiff-backup`](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) sound useful?

Comment: @Mat: In the meantime I've tried `lrzip`, but it was extremely slow (many hours for some 100 GB). However, there might have been a problem with the NTFS partition the data were on.

Comment: @jw013: I don't think `rdiff-backup` would do, as it's efficient with slowly evolving files, while all I have now is a set of old snapshots. Things like `obnam` or `bup` would help (but the former requires a newer system while the latter has still problems with removal from the backup).

Answer (score 2):

If you first tar the files (using `tar cvf my_backup.tar <file list...>`) then any compression tool will do a good job as they will see the data as one big file.

So just tar the files, and then put them in a zip, 7-zip, bzip2, etc. From the tar file, you can try the different compression algorithm and see which one performs best.

Comment: Right, you be sure to use a format that archives and _then_ compresses, instead of one (like .zip) which compresses each file individually and then archives them

Comment: tar + lzma seems to work really well for binary blobs. LZMA is built into newer versions of tar too.

Comment: @Huygens: AFAIK you're wrong. All compression programs I know  work with some window (typically 64 kB) and see nothing beyond it as stated e.g. [here on page 7](http://www.slideshare.net/apenwarr/bup-backup-system-201104).

Comment: @maaartinus this is a shortcoming of gzip then, not tar. Try another compression algorithm, and try to use the options. To experiment you can tar twice the same file and compress the resulting output and see the size as compare to compressing only one file.

Comment: @Huygens You can't expect a compression algorithm go checking if (some prefix of) a 100 MiB chunk appears again in the input. I'd just suggest burning the whole lot to DVDs or such, and hope they won't be needed...

Answer (score 2):

I've had very good luck with 7-Zip. If you have the horsepower, it is capable of operating with a very large window. Make sure your original files are as uncompressed as possible so it can find similarities. (For Excel files in a heterogeneous environment, for example, this means unzipping their contents first, since xlsx files are lightly compressed when they're stored. I was once able to compress 600 MiB+ of almost-redundant Excel version files down to a few hundred KiB.)